# how to get know user has access to particular table in servicenow instance using rest api request

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I want verify supplied user has access to os_list, Core_manufacturer and CMDB_cI_Computers table in servicenow instance using rest api call.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I dont have piece of code. I'm adding this feature to application to check provided user has access to particular table in servicenow before run complete application. I want know how can I verify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceNow does not provide a REST API that you can query to determine whether a particular user has access to a particular table. However, you can query the `sys_user_has_role` table to determine which roles a user has. If you have determined in advance a list of roles which would grant the necessary access, then you can query `sys_user_has_role` to determine whether a particular user has any of these roles.